# How can I blur other windows and not the electron window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So, I want to blur or vibrant other windows or just not the electron app, I'm working on. And blur all the display except the app.

I could vibrant/blur the browser window by adding vibrancy option to the BrowserWindow class, however, I want to blur the other windows, but not the window I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Windows or OS X api that allows you to blur non-focused windows. I guess this is what you are trying to achieve. To blur or darken non-focused *desktop* windows. OS X used to have hidden setting that enabled "focus mode" where only 1 window is active, but that's so hacky that it's not worth discussing.

I'm interested to understand why you need to do that?

Comment: I am working on an application which will blur all the application, except the one that is focused.